# How to change plotly figure size

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, figure

I made the following scatter plot with Plotly:

[image]

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter
import plotly.graph_objs as go


trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=x1_tsne,  # x-coordinates of trace
    y=y1_tsne,  # y-coordinates of trace
    mode="markers ",  # scatter mode (more in UG section 1)
    text=label3,
    opacity=1,
    textposition="top center",
    marker=dict(size=25, color=color_4, symbol=marker_list_2, line=dict(width=0.5)),
    textfont=dict(
        color="black",
        size=18,  # can change the size of font here
        family="Times New Roman",
    ),
)

layout = {
    "xaxis": {
        "showticklabels": False,
        "showgrid": False,
        "zeroline": False,
        "linecolor": "black",
        "linewidth": 2,
        "mirror": True,
        "autorange": False,
        "range": [-40, 40],
    },
    "yaxis": {
        "showticklabels": False,
        "showgrid": False,
        "zeroline": False,
        "linecolor": "black",
        "linewidth": 2,
        "mirror": True,
        "autorange": False,
        "range": [-40, 40],
    },
}

data = [trace1]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

---

I want the height, width, and the markers to be like the plot shown below (made in Matplotlib):

[image]

I tried tuning the range, and using `Autorange`, but they did not help.

---

**EDIT:** The following code worked for me:

```
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=x1_tsne,  # x-coordinates of trace
    y=y1_tsne,  # y-coordinates of trace
    mode="markers +text ",  # scatter mode (more in UG section 1)
    text=label3,
    opacity=1,
    textposition="top center",
    marker=dict(size=25, color=color_4, symbol=marker_list_2, line=dict(width=0.5)),
    textfont=dict(
        color="black",
        size=18,  # can change the size of font here
        family="Times New Roman",
    ),
)
data = [trace1]

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(linecolor="black", linewidth=1, mirror=True),
    yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(linecolor="black", linewidth=1, mirror=True),
    margin=go.layout.Margin(l=50, r=50, b=100, t=100, pad=4),
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename="size-margins")
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Consider using:

```py
fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=800,
    height=800,
)
```

...and then eventually reduce the `size` of your `marker`.

##### Full code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=x1_tsne,  # x-coordinates of trace
    y=y1_tsne,  # y-coordinates of trace
    mode="markers +text ",  # scatter mode (more in UG section 1)
    text=label3,
    opacity=1,
    textposition="top center",
    marker=dict(size=12, color=color_4, symbol=marker_list_2, line=dict(width=0.5)),
    textfont=dict(
        color="black",
        size=18,  # can change the size of font here
        family="Times New Roman",
    ),
)
data = [trace1]

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(linecolor="black", linewidth=1, mirror=True),
    yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(linecolor="black", linewidth=1, mirror=True),
    margin=go.layout.Margin(l=50, r=50, b=100, t=100, pad=4),
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
```

Comment: When I add this before py.iplot, it says figure object has no attribute 'update_layout'.

Comment: Which `plotly` version are you using? Try to add the same values to your `layout` dict. You could eventually use `layout["autosize"] = False` and so on just after defining layout.

Comment: Its version 3.6. With your suggestions, I am able to do it in this version of plotly. Thank you. I tried this before for an interactive plot only.

Comment: Marker size are still the same.

Comment: Even is after trace1, it worked, is that because I am using this layout defined in go.Figure?

Comment: I'd suggest you to move to version 4.5 they changed few things and it will be easier to use documentation.